# mac os terminal shell script for time tracking

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, console

There are two functions : **start** и **stop**
they write the date and time to the file **wrk.txt**
This is what the contents of the file looks like after executing these commands:
`START 10-08-2022 08:00:00`
`STOP 10-08-2022 08:06:33`

function code:

`#!/bin/bash`
 `function start {`
 `echo 'START'  $(date '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') >> ~/Documents/wrk.txt`
 `echo 'work started at:'  $(date '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')`
 `}`

`function stop {`
 `echo 'STOP'  $(date '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') >> ~/Documents/wrk.txt`
 `echo 'work finished at:'  $(date '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')`
}`

Question: how to take the last two lines from the file, remove the word START or STOP and calculate the time difference and save the result to a file

file data before calculations:
`START 10-08-2022 08:00:00`
`STOP 10-08-2022 08:06:33`
expected file data after calculations:
`START 10-08-2022 08:00:00`
`STOP 10-08-2022 08:06:33`
`totalworktime: 00:06:33`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @OXYGEN : cleanest approach to deal with the date+time mess is to convert both to epochs, calculate the diff with straight up subtraction, then re-convert that to year-neutral date-time ( or just time if less than a day)

Answer (score 0):

The following may work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

output_file="${1:-time_delta.out}"
df="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"

start=$(awk '{this=last; last=$0} END{print this}' wrk.txt)
sdate="${start/START /}"
end=$(awk '{this=last; last=$0} END{print last}' wrk.txt)
edate="${end/END /}"

printf "%s\n%s\n" "$start" "$end" >> "${output_file}"
echo $(( $(date -j -f "$df" "${edate}" +%s) \
- $(date -j -f "$df" "${sdate}" +%s) )) \
| awk '{printf("totalworktime: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", ($1/60/60),($1/60%60),($1%60))}' >> "${output_file}"
```

###### 1) Set variable containing desired output file path/name either from first parameter passed to script or will default to `./time_delta.out`.  Set the date format expected from the `wrk.txt` contents.

```
output_file="${1:-time_delta.out}"
df="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

###### 2) Parse the second to the last line and the last line from `wrk.txt` and store the raw lines in variables `start` and `end`.  Remove the leading  `START` and  `END` text from each variable using bash string replacement and store the results in `sdate` and `edate` variables.

```
start=$(awk '{this=last; last=$0} END{print this}' wrk.txt)
sdate="${start/START /}"
end=$(awk '{this=last; last=$0} END{print last}' wrk.txt)
edate="${end/END /}"
```

###### 3) Add the raw `$start` AND `$end` variable contents to the `$output_file`

```
printf "%s\n%s\n" "$start" "$end" >> "${output_file}"
```

###### 4) Convert the `$sdate` and `$edate` values to seconds from the epoch via `date -j -f "$df" "${sdate}" +%s` and `date -j -f "$df" "${edate}" +%s`. Subtract those values to get the delta and pass the result to awk for formatting as `HH:MM:SS` and append to `${output_file}`

```
echo $(( $(date -j -f "$df" "${edate}" +%s) \
- $(date -j -f "$df" "${sdate}" +%s) )) \
| awk '{printf("totalworktime: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", ($1/60/60),($1/60%60),($1%60))}' >> "${output_file}"
```

---

Note, you might also consider replacing your `start` and `stop` functions with a single parameterized
function.  At a minimum, store the date in a variable to avoid duplicate calls to `date`.   Something
like the following:

```
add_time_log() {
    local label="${1:-START}"
    local msg="${2:-work started at}"
    local log_file="${3:-time_log.txt}"
    local now=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    printf "${msg}: ${now}\n"
    printf "${label} ${now}\n" >> "${log_file}"
}
```

You can call the function as follows:

###### The folowing 2 are equivalent due to default parameter values

```
add_time_log
add_time_log START "work started at"
```

###### Adding END log

```
add_time_log END "work finished at"
```

###### Specifying all 3 parameters

```
add_time_log START "work started at" out.txt
add_time_log END "work finished at" out.txt
```